# Maven 3.0.4 NoSuchMethod: ... java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(..)

Tags: maven, guava

I've installed `Maven 3.0.4` with `Homebrew` and whenever I run the `mvn` command I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
```

From Googling the error it seems to be related some sort of *Google guava tool/library* -- which I know nothing about. *I attempted to replaced some Jars in the `/bin` directory of `maven` but it had no affect*

Any help? I don't know where the issue started but now I can't run anything with `mvn`.

Here is what seems to be a related question, but my project doesn't directly reference a `guava*.jar` file:

[NoSuchMethod error getting a gdata service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222665/nosuchmethod-error-getting-a-gdata-service)

Here is complete mvn -X (I am running with a pom.xml in the current directory)

```
    Jordans-iMac:spring-mvc-setup jordanbaucke$ mvn -X
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 01:44:56-0700)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_09, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/aether-api-1.13.1.jar
constituent[1]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
constituent[2]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/aether-impl-1.13.1.jar
constituent[3]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/aether-spi-1.13.1.jar
constituent[4]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
constituent[5]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
constituent[6]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.0.4.jar
constituent[7]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-artifact-3.0.4.jar
constituent[8]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-compat-3.0.4.jar
constituent[9]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-core-3.0.4.jar
constituent[10]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[11]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-model-3.0.4.jar
constituent[12]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-model-builder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[13]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.0.4.jar
constituent[14]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.4.jar
constituent[15]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-settings-3.0.4.jar
constituent[16]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.0.4.jar
constituent[17]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[18]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
constituent[19]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
constituent[20]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[21]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
constituent[22]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
constituent[23]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
constituent[24]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
constituent[25]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/sisu-inject-plexus-2.3.0.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/wagon-file-2.2.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/wagon-http-2.2-shaded.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.2.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    at com.google.inject.internal.InstanceBindingImpl.<init>(InstanceBindingImpl.java:51)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toInstance(BindingBuilder.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$RootModule.configure(InjectorShell.java:329)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:470)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

**Update**

Downgraded to Java 1.6, uninstall Macports as well. Same problem.

Comment: can you provide some more info? Are you just running 'mvn' or are there arguments that you are passing? Are you running it in a project directory with a pom file? Run it again with -X parameter and provide the last 10 lines or so.

Comment: I'm very wary of installing Java stuff with Homebrew; I always just install the normal Java way (untar) and run it that way.

Comment: @DaveNewton I reinstalled with _normal java way (untar)_ and I get the same error!

Comment: It looks like I am running 10.6.8 and khmarbase is running 10.5.8 and you are running 10.8.2, so there may be an issue with the mac jdk

Comment: OSX As displayed in output: 10.8.2

Comment: @jordan.baucke Change the value of JAVA_HOME (Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/jre) into Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/

Comment: @kldavis4 `OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.2"`

Comment: @khmarbaise _done_ `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home` same issue

Comment: @jordan.baucke Have you several bin folder in your PATH variable? What does *which mvn* says ?

Comment: Ok reinstall `mvn` with macports this time to keep the path updated and updated java.

Comment: Hmm, are we sure this is a problem with Homebrew? I'm running Maven installed using Homebrew and it's working just fine. Do you get the error if you run `mvn` from a folder containing no `pom.xml? as well?

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg I get it everywhere I run a `mvn` command I've uninstalled the `Homebrew` and the `tar/zip`, and am now trying to install `Mac Ports` version

Comment: What does `env|grep MAVEN_OPTS` show?

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg it doesn't return anything...

Comment: Since it fails for **all** invocations of `mvn` even those without a `pom.xml` file present, all it fails for **all** versions you've tried - it must be something in your environment that is somehow added to the `mvn` classpath..

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg hmmm I have no idea what it could be... or how to fix it

Comment: I suggest troubleshooting this by switching to an earlier jdk, assuming you have it installed. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/multiple-java-versions-support-on-os-x-and-java-home-location for how to switch jdk on mac.

Comment: @kldavis4 Nope, now down to java 1.6, same problem. I'm considering erasing my OS and reinstalling.

Comment: when you run mvn -X with java 1.6, what is the value of Java home? Is it: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home ?

Comment: The issue is that the maven classpath has the wrong version of guava in it. Maven should be using the MAVEN_HOME environment variable for building the classpath. If you look in MAVEN_HOME, the lib directory contains the core set of jars the maven runtime requires. There you should see a sisu-guava-0.9.9 jar. That is the correct version for Maven 3.0.4. Make sure there is nothing in the lib/ext directory.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the wrong set of the MAVEN_HOME variable cause it's pointing to a wrong folder

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec
```

Furthermore the installation your are using doesn't look like the default from maven.apache.org download page.

You should download the [apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz](http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz) from maven.apache.org unpack it and point the MAVEN_HOME to the root of the extracted archive something like:

```
/usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4
```

and put the bin folder /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin into the PATH. If you call

```
mvn --version
```

something more or less similar like the following should be printed out:

```
mac:~ km$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_26, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.5.8", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
mac:~ km$
```

Comment: Just added the output from installing it from the tarball / zip to original question. Same problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the version of Maven you have installed has a dependency on an incorrect version of Guava. Maven 3 does apparently depend on Guice and Guava, so the error isn't totally spurious. This may be a problem with the Homebrew package that you are using having the incorrect library dependencies (it appears to be using 0.9.9 of Guava. You should raise this with the package maintainer and/or install a tarball / zip version instead of using Homebrew.

Comment: Just added the output from installing it from the tarball / zip to original question. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue on OS X, with maven 3.2.2 and Java 1.8. 'mvn clean test' was failing with no class definition found error.
Upgraded maven to 3.3.9 and was able to successfully run mvn commands.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that some of your jars would be having dependency on google/guava jars and if they're not in build path or if multiple of them are there it might raise inconsistency hence the error.
A quick solution could be add latest version of guava to your pom

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now check in dependency hierarchy if any of your Jar apart from guava is referring to any other older jar of guava/google-collections. If so then exclude it, something like this

```
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
```