# dailytracker setting getting exception

Tags: java, google-ads-api

Type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableTypes(AltFormat.java:399)
    com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableXmlTypes(AltFormat.java:387)
    com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<clinit>(AltFormat.java:49)
    com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:558)
    com.netelixir.lxr.dailyTracker.services.GoogleServiceCreator.createSpreadSheetService(GoogleServiceCreator.java:22)
    com.netelixir.lxr.dailyTracker.services.GoogleServiceCreator.getSpreadSheetService(GoogleServiceCreator.java:36)
    com.netelixir.lxr.dailyTracker.services.SpreadSheetUtil.<init>(SpreadSheetUtil.java:39)
    com.netelixir.lxr.dailyTracker.DailyTrackerActionForm.validate(DailyTrackerActionForm.java:183)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processValidate(RequestProcessor.java:950)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:198)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: Could you give us more information about when or where the error is coming from? Maybe your code.

Comment: see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222665/nosuchmethod-error-getting-a-gdata-service